# mysqli_query doesn't give results for email query

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a database in phpmyadmin and im trying to query the email fields from it, and it doesn't seem to work. The email field type is varchar and they contain the `@` special character: `example@domain.com` I tried querying from the phpmyadmin console too but with no success.

Im using the following mysqli_query to get the specific fields:

ex: `$email="example@domain.com"`

```
$qres = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='".$email."'")
or die("Query error!");
$match = mysqli_num_rows($qres);
echo $match;
```

The $match variable returns 0 which means the query works but doesn't return any result, but my database contains multiple entries with the specific email. Im guessing that is something to do with the @ special character, but not really sure.

Comment: How do you read the information returned by that query? The query itself looks fine, that shouldn't cause the trouble.

Comment: Please switch to [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: there may not be any email matching in db

Comment: Im not interested in the querry itself im interested in the number of rows it returns. I store it in the $qres variable.

Comment: Trust me :) there are alot of entries with that email address.

Comment: trust your eyes. there aren't.

Comment: especially if you tried in phpadmin with same result

Comment: is it possible you have leading/trailing spaces around the email, so the `=` does not work? You could use [`TRIM()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) to check. `$qres = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE TRIM(email)='".$email."'") or die("Querry error!");`

Comment: I made some test and entered an email without @ character and the query works... So should i avoid placing @ special characters in db;

Comment: there is absolutely nothing wrong with @ character. And with *real* tests you would see that

Comment: I found the solution :) i cannot post it because im a newbie here, but the problem was database related. I left collation setting of the email field blank which set it to default latin1_sweedish latin/sweedish charset... I changed it to utf8_unicode_ci and it worked like a charm :) Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

use like keyword in sql statement like this

```
$qres = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email like '%$email%'");
```

Comment: @mohsen aliazadeh: The problem is with the @ character because on normal entry without the @ character the querry works fine. Is there a way to to insert emails (ex: example@domain.com) in the db and retrieve them? just tryied your aproach and it doesnt work.

Comment: @TutsekRobert please rein your imagination .

Comment: @Your Common Sense I know that are alot of genius programers out there with like u with great logic and imagination im not one of them unfortunately so sorry to insult u with this code... Tryed with half of your code same result 0.

Comment: I found the solution :) i cannot post it because im a newbie here, but the problem was database related. I left collation setting of the email field blank which set it to default `latin1_sweedish` latin/sweedish charset... I changed it to `utf8_unicode_ci` and it worked like a charm :) Thank you for your answers!

Comment: @TutsekRobert all symbols allowed in email are absolutely the same in latin1 and utf-8. So, this shoot is missed again.

Comment: @Your Common Sense: Um, re tested it again :S and what u said is true. Although i made quite a few modifications beside that. And there is a slight chance that i typed , instead of . when registering email addresses and that's why the query didn't succeed. :)